# Installing wordpress site on vistaprint

Tags: wordpress, hosting

Is it possible to install a WordPress website onto VistaPrint platform?
I have tried asking their live chat but they had no clue what I am referring to. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Yes they do provide website hosting

Comment: They have a website toolkit, but that doesn't allow you to upload your custom stuff. This means you also cannot get a WordPress setup up and running. You can only register with them and click together a website with their tool and you are limited to what this tool offers.